# why are all columns being pulled by my macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a quick question in regards to why my macro is not working. I do not know vba, but I think I am requesting it pull P14:S, but it is placing all columns A14:end into my master sheet where I am collecting data. Here is how I am doing this:

```
Sub Consolidate()
    'Author:     Jerry Beaucaire'
    'Date:       9/15/2009     (2007 compatible)  (updated 4/29/2011)
    'Summary:    Merge files in a specific folder into one master sheet (stacked)
    '            Moves imported files into another folder
    ' Edited/altered by me

    Dim fName As String, fPath As String, fPathDone As String
    Dim LR As Long, NR As Long
    Dim wbData As Workbook, wsMaster As Worksheet

    'Setup
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False           'speed up macro execution
    Application.EnableEvents = False             'turn off other macros for now
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False            'turn off system messages for now

    Set wsMaster = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Master") 'sheet report is built into

    With wsMaster
        If MsgBox("Clear the old data first?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
            .UsedRange.Offset(1).EntireRow.Clear
            NR = 2
        Else
            NR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'appends data to existing data
        End If

        'Path and filename (edit this section to suit)
        fPath = "C:\Users\jc\Desktop\Test\"      'remember final \ in this string"
        fPathDone = fPath & "Imported\"          'remember final \ in this string
        On Error Resume Next
        MkDir fPathDone                          'creates the completed folder if missing
        On Error GoTo 0
        fName = Dir(fPath & "New BM Analysis test.xlsm") 'listing of desired files, edit filter as desired

        'Import a sheet from found files
        Do While Len(fName) > 0
            If fName <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then   'don't reopen this file accidentally
                Set wbData = Workbooks.Open(fPath & fName) 'Open file

                'This is the section to customize, replace with your own action code as needed
                LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row
                Range("P14:S" & LR).Copy .Range("A" & NR)
                wbData.Close False               'close file
                NR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Next row
                'Name fPath & fName As fPathDone & fName           'move file to IMPORTED folder
            End If
            fName = Dir                          'ready next filename
        Loop
    End With

ErrorExit:                                       'Cleanup
    ActiveSheet.Columns.AutoFit
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True             'turn system alerts back on
    Application.EnableEvents = True              'turn other macros back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True            'refreshes the screen
End Sub
```

Does anyone know why the columns I request are not being pulled? It could be I am asking the wrong way.

Comment: `Range("P14:S" & LR).EntireRow.Copy`  here `EntireRow` means the entire row - it's not restricted to the original range you specify.  Just remove that.

Comment: thank you Tim, this is almost it! It pulls P14-all and P15-S15 down until theres no more data. Do you see why it would pull the entire P row?

Comment: `Range("P14:S" & LR).Copy` can only copy a regular rectangular range, so something else is going on with your code.

Comment: Also worth noting that `Range("P14:S" & LR).Copy .Range("A" & NR)` and `Range("P14:S" & LR).Copy .Range("A" & NR)` are both working on the `ActiveWorkbook`. While the `ActiveWorkbook` should be equal to `wbData`, this bit should be qualified just in case, otherwise it *could* cause an issue.

Comment: Brandon, I think you mentioned the same lines twice, but said "&". I am not sure if I understand. Why does wbData work better?

Comment: @JChase Using `wbData.ActiveSheet.Range("P14:S" & LR).Copy .Range("A" & NR)` instead of `Range("P14:S" & LR).Copy .Range("A" & NR)` is better because it ensures that the copy is being done from the active sheet in the newly opened workbook, even if (for instance, while debugging) a user (or developer) clicks on another workbook.  (And the use of `ActiveSheet` is a bad idea too - you should specify **which** sheet in `wbData` you want to copy from, just in case someone clicks on a different sheet in that workbook.)

Comment: @YowE3K ah, thank you. I understand